# How can I configure in Thymeleaf the base URL?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf for the templates of a web application.

When I make a link I use a URL like this:

```
<img class="info" 
    src="../../../resources/img/image.png"
    th:src="@{/resources/img/image.png}" />
```

How can I configure the base URL in Thymeleaf?

I need this because my application runs in the current URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

And it works fine, but then it redirects to:

```
http://www.myapp.com/
```

Then the images was search in:

```
http://www.myapp.com/myapp/resources/img/image.png
```

instead of:

```
http://www.myapp.com/resources/img/image.png
```

I want something like:

```
<property name="baseURL" value="http://www.myapp.com"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [Server-relative URLs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/standardurlsyntax.html):

`<img class="info" th:src="@{~/resources/img/image.png}" />`

UPD
Actual link to [url part of Thymeleaf 2.1. tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the baseUrl as parameter to template. Then: `<a th:href="${baseUrl + '/my/uri?maybe=' + someParam}"`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Merci Toshko! I needed to embed a baseUrl since I'm using Thymeleaf to process email templates.